# Is it a bad idea to #include C source files to select implementation of an API?

Tags: c

I am working on a C project where I'm defining an API, and then have multiple different implementations of that API, something like the below:

```
|-api.h
|-implementation_1.c
|-implementation_2.c
```

I'm working with CMake, so currently to select which implementation is used by the application, the user has to set a define, e.g. `-DIMPLEMENTATION_SEL_1` and also select which of the `implemmentation_x.c` files are included in the build.

I was thinking it could be nice to simplify the selection to depend only on the define, by adding an extra source file with #includes to the implementation-specific source files, something like this...

```
|-api.h
|-implementation.c
|-implementation_1.c
|-implementation_2.c
```

```
//implementation.c

#if defined IMPLEMENTATION_SEL_1
    #include "implementation_1.c"
#elif defined IMPLEMENTATION_SEL_2
    #include "implementation_2.c"
#else
    #error "Invalid API implementation selected"
#endif
```

This way my CMake file only ever has to specify `implementation.c` as part of the build, and only the define should change to select between implementations.

My question is: is there any reason I should avoid this approach? I've heard it's bad practice to include source files, but to me it seems in this case it might be cleaner than the alternatives

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we should not include source files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002266/why-we-should-not-include-source-files-in-c)

Comment: I would leave this up to the build-environment if possible.

Comment: But if you compile `implementation_1.c` and `implementation_2.c` you will get duplicated (tri-plicated!) symbosl.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is the most correct way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right, it makes a lot more sense to manage it that way, thanks!